# cron.daily clairification

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have been fiddling with cron. If you schedule a script to run daily and your computer is off when acron has it scheduled will it run if you turn your computer on later in the day?

Answer (score 2):

cron.daily is scheduled to run once a day at specific time. If your computer is off at that time, it misses it.

Take a look at **/etc/crontab** to see when it is scheduled to run. In there you will see the schedule setup.. and it follows this structure:

MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD

You should see something similar to...

```
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Which means run the /etc/cron.daily file at 2 Minutes past 4AM day of every week of every month

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you usually have `anachron` installed. It will run your daily jobs, next time
you start the machine, if the intervall between the last runs of a job was greater than one day. It will not run a job later in the day, if your machine was turned of temporarily.

From the man page:

> Anacron can be used to execute commands periodically, with a 
>   frequency    specified in days.  Unlike cron(8), it does not assume
>   that the machine    is running continuously.  Hence, it can be used on
>   machines that aren't    running 24 hours a day, to control daily,
>   weekly, and monthly jobs that    are usually controlled by cron.
>
> When executed, Anacron reads a list of jobs from a configuration 
>   file,    normally  /etc/anacrontab  (see anacrontab(5)).  This file
>   contains the    list of jobs that Anacron controls.  Each job entry
>   specifies a  period    in  days,  a  delay  in  minutes,  a unique job
>   identifier, and a shell    command.
>
> For each job, Anacron checks whether this job has been executed in 
>   the    last  n  days,  where  n is the period specified for that job. 
>   If not,    Anacron runs the job's shell command, after waiting for the
>   number  of    minutes specified as the delay parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added this line to /etc/anacrontab:   (1       5       cron.daily      php5 /var/www/mazda/backup.php)  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Happy is right. I can add that if you need your script to run daily but you are not sure whether your computer will be on at the requested time, you can put your script in the folder **/etc/cron.daily** and it will be run at startup.
You can also use [Anacron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Cron is a daemon which once per minute checks the configuration and runs configured commands. Also your cronjobs defined in distro-specific cron.daily is executed at a specific time, which is often defined in /etc/crontab ( read all configurations in /etc/cron.daily etc. )

If you want to make sure your job is executed once per day, no matter when the machine is running, I suggest to add it to your `/etc/rc.local` to run the command after startup.

**EDIT**
Seems like the default cron on Ubuntu, anacron, is doing better. Read Mithrandir's answer